# Как обработать длинный JSON в Android

Tags: java, android, json

Добрый день, создал приложение, реализовал аккаунт пользователя. В профиле пользователя беру JSON данные и вывожу через `listview` в активити, но столкнулся с такой проблемой: структура профиля расширилась, соответственно получаемый JSON очень большой, и никак не поместиться в одном `item`. А мне нужно расширить как-то этот item, подскажите в какую сторону копать?

```
// Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                SpecialTechical person = new SpecialTechical();

                                person.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                person.setType(obj.getString("type"));
                                person.setNumber(obj.getString("number"));
                                person.setImg(obj.getString("image"));
                                person.setAddress(obj.getString("side"));
                                person.setCom(obj.getString("com"));
                                person.setAge(obj.getString("age"));
                                person.setPrice(obj.getString("price"));
                                person.setTime(obj.getString("data"));

                                names.add(person);
                        }
```

**Мой Адаптер:**

```
public class NewOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder2> {

Context c;
ArrayList<SpecialTechical> specialTechicals;
Dialog dialog;
final String[] texts = TeachersDisplayActivity.subject;
public NewOrderAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<SpecialTechical> specialTechicals) {
    this.c = c;
    this.specialTechicals = specialTechicals;
}

@Override
public MyHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.it3,parent,false);
    MyHolder2 holder=new MyHolder2(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder2 holder, final int position) {
   PicassoClient.downloadImage(c, specialTechicals.get(position).getImg(), holder.img);
    String n=specialTechicals.get(position).getType();
    holder.nameTxt.setText(texts[Integer.parseInt(n)]);
    holder.subject.setText(specialTechicals.get(position).getCom());
    holder.region2.setText(specialTechicals.get(position).getPrice());


    holder.date.setText(specialTechicals.get(position).getTime());
 //   holder.name.setText(specialTechicals.get(position).getName());
```

Comment: Для начала, объясните, как именно вы выводите JSON в ListView.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    final String teacherName = name.getString("name");

Comment: передаю эти данные в адаптер,а там вывожу  в item

Comment: А добавить новые поля в Model и в Item новые TextView нельзя?

Comment: подскажите пж ,могу оплатить  как туториал

Comment: То есть теперь у вас там будет не только `name`, а и другая информация? Что вам мешает поместить в item и ее?

Comment: Можете выложить ваш Model, Item.xml и код где выводите JSON?

Comment: Смотрите например ,у меня 20 свойств профиля(имя,фамилия,возраст итд),как мне создать в одном layout столько столбец,мне же нужно как то расширить адаптер?

Comment: у кого есть время ,покажу код по скайпу meirlen777,за потраченное время оплачу через  qiwi  500руб

Comment: Сегодня я дожен решить эту задачку

Comment: Так выложите ваш Model, Item.xml и код где выводите JSON, здесь поможем...

Comment: Во первых, покажите код. Во вторых, вам нужен кастомный ListVIew с кастомным элементом списка. В третьих, вам нужно создать класс, который будет представлять модель вашего элемента списка.

Comment: Закинул код ,посмотрите пж

Comment: Так это же RecyclerView а не ListView

Comment: да ,как бы суть одна и та же,вывод json в item,посмотрели код?как быть в моем случае?

Comment: Примерно написал... Посмотрите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите, набросал, но логика должна быть понятной.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Model> objects;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, R.layout.main_row, objects);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void setData(){
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Model person = new Model();

                                person.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                person.setType(obj.getString("type"));
                                person.setNumber(obj.getString("number"));
                                person.setImg(obj.getString("image"));
                                person.setAddress(obj.getString("side"));
                                person.setCom(obj.getString("com"));
                                person.setAge(obj.getString("age"));
                                person.setPrice(obj.getString("price"));
                                person.setTime(obj.getString("data"));

                                objects.add(person);
                            }
         ......................................
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class MainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Model> objects;

    public MainAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Model> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
        this.resource = resource;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.tv_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.tv_type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
            holder.tv_number = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
            holder.tv_side = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSide);
            holder.tv_com = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCom);
            holder.tv_age = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
            holder.tv_price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            holder.tv_data = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvData);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_name.setText(objects.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_type.setText(objects.get(position).getType());
        holder.tv_number.setText(objects.get(position).getNumber());
        holder.tv_side.setText(objects.get(position).getSide());
        holder.tv_com.setText(objects.get(position).getCom());
        holder.tv_age.setText(objects.get(position).getAge());
        holder.tv_price.setText(objects.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.tv_data.setText(objects.get(position).getData());


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tv_name;
        private TextView tv_type;
        private TextView tv_number;
        private TextView tv_side;
        private TextView tv_com;
        private TextView tv_age;
        private TextView tv_price;
        private TextView tv_data;
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String number;
    private String image;
    private String side;
    private String com;
    private String age;
    private String price;
    private String data;

    public Model() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(String side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public String getCom() {
        return com;
    }

    public void setCom(String com) {
        this.com = com;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

**Main_row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvType"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvNumber"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvData"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvSide"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvCom"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvAge"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: спасибо,надеюсь поможет